# Polymer custom element will not style

Tags: css, polymer

I have a custom Polymer element, which contians a paper-dialog and a paper-item.

I cannot style the paper-item when the dialog's layered property is set to true.

```html
<polymer-element name="myElement">
 <template>
  <style>
   paper-item.myClass {
    background: #B7AAFA;
   }
   
   html /deep/ paper-item.myClass {
    background: #B7AAFA;
   }
  </style>
  <paper-dialog id="myDialog" layered="true">
   <paper-item class="myClass">
    Some Words
   </paper-item>
  </paper-dialog>
 </template>
 <script>
  Polymer(
   ...
  );
 </script>
</polymer-element>
```

I have tried just referencing it by ID, using /deep/, and variations of ::shadow, with the style block in and outside of the template.

Can you see anything wrong with my set up?

Thanks

Comment: i have seen this in a app i am working on. i know this isn't the best solution but i have just been inlining css. <paper-item style="background:B7AAFA"> something strange with with css scoping in paper-dialog

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, i see the issue. paper-dialog moves the entire element into a core-overlay. So just move the class definitions into the paper-dialog, e.g.

```
<paper-dialog id="myDialog" layered="true">
 <style>
  .myClass {
    background:red;
  }
 </style>
 <paper-item class="myClass">
  Some Words
 </paper-item>
</paper-dialog>
```

That guarantees that your custom styles will be moved as well.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a codepen example on how to solve this.  [example](http://codepen.io/Nevraeka/pen/JomwpY?editors=101)

```js
document.querySelector('a').addEventListener('click', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var deepTest      = document.querySelector('deep-selector-test')
   , dialogSetting = deepTest.getAttribute('layer') === 'false' ? 'true' : 'false';
  deepTest.setAttribute('layer', dialogSetting );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.polymer-project.org/0.5/components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents.min.js?20150311"></script>
<link rel="import" href="https://www.polymer-project.org/0.5/components/polymer/polymer.html">
<link type="import" href="https://www.polymer-project.org/0.5/components/paper-item/paper-item.html">
<link type="import" href="https://www.polymer-project.org/0.5/components/paper-dialog/paper-dialog.html">

<polymer-element name="deep-selector-test"
                 attributes="layer">
   <template>
      <style>
         .myClass {
            background: #B7AAFA;
         }
   
         paper-dialog[layered=true] .myClass {
            background: red;
         }
      </style>
      <paper-dialog id="myDialog" layered="true">
         <paper-item class="myClass">Some Words</paper-item>
      </paper-dialog>
   </template>
   <script>
      Polymer('deep-selector-test', {
      layer: false,
      layerChanged: function(oldVal, newVal){
        this.shadowRoot.querySelector('paper-dialog').setAttribute('layered', newVal);
      }
    });
   </script>
</polymer-element>

<h4>
  <a href="#">Change layered property</a>
</h4>
<deep-selector-test layer="false"></deep-selector-test>
```

Comment: Please note that my solution has a click issue where the first click doesn't work. It's not core to the problem so I left it in - just want to let you know though